# php parse h tag with style

Tags: php, parsing

I couldn't find anything on parsing this sort of example.

```
<h3 style="color:red; font-size:24px;">This contest is still open.</h3>
```

Here is my code, but it doesn't work :( I was to parse this exact H3 tag because there are many  tags on the page but they don't have  `style="color:red; font-size:24px;"` so I only want to return content from H3 with `style="color:red; font-size:24px;"` on them

```
$html = get_file_content('http://www.website.com/contest.php');
preg_match( '#<h3[^>]*>(.*?)</h3>#i', $html, $match );
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: Every time I parse a H tag, I do it with style ;)

Comment: As for the regex, it most likely failed due to \newlines in the text content. In this case the `#is` flag would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)? It was designed for parsing HTML; regex wasn't.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// Assuming it supports URL, if not, put `file_get_contents()` in there.
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.website.com/contest.php');

foreach( $dom->getElemetsByTagName('h3') as $h3) {
   if ($h3->hasAttribute('style') AND
       $h3->getAttribute('style') == 'color:red; font-size:24px;'
   ) {
      echo $h3->nodeValue;
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I get this error "Call to a member function loadHTML() on a non-object" does it mean that the url i am using does not support html

Comment: @FAFAFOHI I stuffed up, that should be `loadHTMLFile()`. Make sure you have DOMDocument too.

Answer (score 2):

Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. Use a real HTML parser. Like [this one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Or [many others](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20html%20parsewr#hl=en&sa=X&ei=rr2bTcC2HcaWtweJ2pS4Bw&ved=0CBcQvwUoAQ&q=php%20html%20parser&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=23c2bd992ac36d9d).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that you shouldn't be using regex, but given that you are I think this is closer to what you want.

```
preg_match( '#<h3[^>]+?>(.*?)</h3>#i', $html, $match );
```